# how can I hardcode a private key in bitcoinJ - ECKey constructor?

Tags: private-key, bitcoinj, private-key-import

Can someone please explain how to use the following constructor (listed [here](https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/core/ECKey.html)):

```
ECKey(BigInteger priv, org.spongycastle.math.ec.ECPoint pub)
```

Say my private key is: `priv = "L4...5"`.

1. How do I get the big integer representation of it (in other words, and if I understood correctly, is there a function to go from `check58` to `biginteger`?) , and
2. what about the second parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are after is getting an `ECKey` object for that private key, then Bitcoinj has a `DumpedPrivateKey` class for just such an occasion.

```
import org.bitcoinj.core.ECKey;
import org.bitcoinj.core.DumpedPrivateKey;
import org.bitcoinj.params.MainNetParams;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String priv = "L4...5";
        ECKey key = DumpedPrivateKey.fromBase58(MainNetParams.get(), priv).getKey();
    }

}
```

If you would like to use an `ECKey` constructor explicitly, then you should be able to get the code you need from here:

> https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/release-0.14/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/core/DumpedPrivateKey.java#L70-L91

---

With respect to the constructor you listed, it is a protected constructor, so it's probably not one you would be looking to use. It lists a private key and public key parameters. The private key may be null if the `ECKey` instance is only going to be used for verifying signatures, not actually producing them. The public key must not be null, and it saves time by not needing to re-compute the public key, which is a CPU intensive operation.

Note that most of the `public ECKey` constructors are deprecated. The preferred way of creating the `ECKey` objects now is to use the static factory methods.

Comment: Thank you very very very very much... worked fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can call the public static method of ECKeyclass,  fromPrivate(byte[] privKeyBytes, boolean compressed). The public key is calculated from it (this is slow), either compressed or not. Eg.,

```
        String privateKey = "Your Private Key";
        byte[] b = privateKey.getBytes();
        ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(b, true);
```

or

```
BigInteger privKey = Base58.decodeToBigInteger(privateKey );
key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privKey);
```

https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.13/org/bitcoinj/core/ECKey.html