# How to transform a private key into an ECKey?

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I´d like to construct an ECKey from a hardcoded private key but it´s not working...

## First try

If I run the code in this [example](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/SendRequest.java) the key import is working just fine. But since I actually want so send money I need to import my own key...

I tried this private key L48r9sYN2dtsWHWwJ1Xez27W7a3X7RvG6obrmVgU2JLTFQeUCnkh and used [this site](https://www.bitaddress.org/bitaddress.org-v3.3.0-SHA256-dec17c07685e1870960903d8f58090475b25af946fe95a734f88408cef4aa194.html) to generate it. When I try to make the private key an ECKey like this:

```
ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(Base58.decodeToBigInteger("L48r9sYN2dtsWHWwJ1Xez27W7a3X7RvG6obrmVgU2JLTFQeUCnkh"));
```

I´m getting the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: private key exceeds 32 bytes: 304 bits
```

## Second try

I tried the solution form [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46737/how-can-i-hardcode-a-private-key-in-bitcoinj-eckey-constructor) with this code

```
String priv = "L48r9sYN2dtsWHWwJ1Xez27W7a3X7RvG6obrmVgU2JLTFQeUCnkh";
ECKey key1 = DumpedPrivateKey.fromBase58(TestNet3Params.get(), priv).getKey();
```

Which leads me to this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bitcoinj.core.AddressFormatException$WrongNetwork: Version code of address did not match acceptable versions for network: 128
at org.bitcoinj.core.DumpedPrivateKey.fromBase58(DumpedPrivateKey.java:59)
at com.javamaster.TicTacToeApplication.main(TicTacToeApplication.java:42)
```

## Third try

I tried another solution form [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46737/how-can-i-hardcode-a-private-key-in-bitcoinj-eckey-constructor)

```
    byte[] b = priv.getBytes();
    System.out.println(priv);
    ECKey key3 = ECKey.fromPrivate(b, true);
```

It results in the same exception as from the second try.

What is wrong with the key? Should I use another way to generate the private key?

Answer (score 1):

The valid private key is `L48r9sYN2dtsWHWwJ1Xez27W7a3X7RvG6obrmVgU2JLTFQeUCn` not `L48r9sYN2dtsWHWwJ1Xez27W7a3X7RvG6obrmVgU2JLTFQeUCnkh`. You mistyped and added "kh"